# Listing divisors of a number

Tags: number-theory

I created a list with all divisors of 18000:

```
list1 = Divisors[18000]
```

I did an analysis to identify which of these numbers are divisible by $15$, but the result I got was `True` and `False`

```
list2 = Divisible[#, 15] & /@ list1
```

Is there a function that shows the numbers and not boolean operation?

Comment: Try `Pick[list1, list2]`.

Comment: Thanks. I try too... Select[list1, Divisible[#, 15] &]

Comment: You might find `GroupBy[list1, Divisible[#, 15] &]` useful as well.